# Quotient topology of projective plane

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

Can anyone please explain the projective space?

[image]

I want to understand how the square and circle (in the first row) is equivalent?

Please help me.

Comment: A homeomorphism from the square to the disk is given by $ (x, y) \mapsto \frac{||(x,y)||_{\infty}}{||(x,y)||_2}(x, y) $ if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $(0, 0) \mapsto (0, 0)$. You should then verify that it respects the equivalence relations on the square and the disk.

Comment: Considering the square is $I^2$, $p$ is $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: contract both $a$ sides then you get a circle.

Comment: This is taken from Sophia N. Potoczak's thesis?